# Usar nome completo da classe ou importar?

Tags: .net, importação

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

caso eu vá usar uma classe específica apenas uma vez em um local, devo importar toda ela lá em cima no código?

Exemplo:

Suponhamos que eu queira pegar uma informação do `web.config` em uma classe, apensa uma informação, e apenas uma vez, é preferível eu fazer

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["minha_info"]
```

ou

```
using System.Configuration;

// ...

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["minha_info"]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, é exatamente isso que eu queria